# click on Image display image on new window

Tags: html, css

I get data from the database in which is images and some other fields, now I want that when I click on the Image they open in the new window my code is

```
<a target="_blank" href="#">
                  <img alt="" src="<%#"data:Image/png;base64,"+Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("ImageData"))  %>"" width="200" height="200" />

             </a>
```

what should I do this img pass to next window and display large or actual size

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add some javascript to your code.

**// HTML**

```
 <a target="_blank" href="#" onClick='test(this)'>
 <img alt="" src="<%#"data:Image/png;base64,"+ Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("ImageData"))  %>"" />
 </a>
```

**//     Javascript Code**

```
 function test(element) {
        var newTab = window.open();
        setTimeout(function() {
            newTab.document.body.innerHTML = element.innerHTML;
        }, 500);
        return false;
    }
```

[Demo Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ArifhShigri/y92j51bb/1/)

Answer (score 2):

The `href` attribute of the `a` tag has to contain the same filepath as the `src` attribute inside the `img` tag. You already added `target="_blank"`, so the image will open in a new window, in original size, showing nothing else than the image.

Comment: you can say that:         <a target="_blank" href="<%#"data:Image/png;base64,"+Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("ImageData"))  %>"">
                  <img alt="" src="<%#"data:Image/png;base64,"+Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("ImageData"))  %>"" width="200" height="200" />

             </a>

Comment: I was talking about the filepath in general. Inside of what you wrote in the filepath you have several double quotes which almost certainly will cause the filepath not to work, because the first of them actually closes the `href` attribute again, leaving the rest without meaning. So you should use single quotes around the attribute value, like `href=' .....'`

Comment: I did exactly that and get `Gone, Error 410`

Answer (score 0):

You can do by this:

// html

```
<a target="_blank" href="#" onClick='zoom(this)'>
 <img alt="" id="choicedPhoto" src="<%#"data:Image/png;base64,"+ Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("ImageData"))  %>"" />
 </a>
```

// script

```
function zoom(element) {
         var newTab = window.open();
         var data = document.getElementById("choicedPhoto").getAttribute("src");
         setTimeout(function () {
             newTab.document.body.innerHTML = "<img src='" + data + "'>";
         }, 500);
         return false;
     }
```

you have no size limit (as original img)